# Unintended install and default to Dolphin File Manager on Ubuntu 18.04.03 (gnome)?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, gnome, kde, dolphin

I recently updated a system running Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.  The user just asked me a question involving a "different" file manager and I noticed that, instead of the legacy gnome file manager, the system presents the dolphin file manager to the user.  I did not install dolphin.  The user is not admin on the system and doesn't know how to install applications. Anyone know why dolphin would be installed on the system?  I know dolphin is associated with the kde install, but did the 16>18 upgrade install dolphin vs gnome file manager?  Nothing turned up on a google search.

For security reasons, I try to maintain a rational paranoia with respect to unexpected applications replacing other applications.

Comment: *but did the 16>18 upgrade install dolphin vs gnome file manager?* No! Dolphin must have been installed by "someone" before the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Well...didn't think I'd installed it and she'd never seen that file manager before today.  A bit of a puzzle...